# Appending an element in nested list comprehension python

Tags: python

My (derailed) mind would like to do the following:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = [list([a for a in list2]).append(n) for n in list1]
```

to output this:

> [['a', 'b', 'c', '1'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '2'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '3']]

**only** using single line list comprehensions (yes I'm in blinded by Haskell love).

Instead it outputs a list of 3 `None` type items which is understandable as I'm getting the output of `append` 3 times.

I think there's a key python idea I'm missing here on how I could make this work (or me being completely illogical), any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to over-complicate things.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = ['a','b','c']
>>> [list2 + [x] for x in list1]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 'c', 2], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3]]
```

Comment: Solved the actual dummy thing so I'll accept your answer. The point I don't get is how could I use functions that return something in list comprehensions. Is it very uncommon and should be avoided?

Comment: List comprehension only works with functions that return something. `append` does not return anything, it modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. List concatenation returns the new list without modifying the original.

Comment: Also can do: `[[*list2, x] for x in list1]`

Comment: So there's no way to output the list that is modified in-place instead of `None`s, using `append`?

Comment: If you did that, the result would be ``[['a','b','c',1],['a','b','c',1,2],['a','b','c',1,2,3]]``

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I thought so as well for a moment, but note they copy the list before appending.

Comment: @KellyBundy Could you just send what you're thinking over? :) Thanks a lot guys I'll take it from here!

Comment: @Aris `list3 = [(a := list([a for a in list2])).append(n) or a for n in list1]` works (but it's bad)

Comment: @Aris Ha, just realized you even make a copy of a copy. Making double sure, eh?

Comment: @KellyBundy I promise I did not do it on purpose :') Can you explain why I'm making a copy of a copy?

Comment: @Aris Only you know why. You first copy with a list comprehension, then with the `list` call.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm embarrassed, I'll quadruple check what I upload here ouf